# Is there a way to programmatically override a datasource url with nest config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, prisma

I've got a `app.config.ts` file with plenty of config variables that look like this:

```js
export const exampleConfig = (config: ConfigService) => {
    // Do stuff

    return config.get('EXAMPLE')
}
```

And I've got my `schema.prisma` file which requires a database URL... Currently, I use this config file on my `app.module.ts` and on my `main.ts`:

**AppModule:**

```js
      ExampleModule.forRootAsync({
         imports: [ConfigModule],
         inject: [ConfigService],
         useFactory: exampleConfig
    }),
```

**Main:**

```js
[...]
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { exampleConfig } from './config/app.config';
[...]


(async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);

  [...]

  app.exampleCallThatNeedsConfig(exampleConfig(configService));

  await app.listen(3000);
})();
```

Notice how I always use @nestjs/config configService on my `app.config.ts`? The thing here is, my `schema.prisma` file needs a DB_URL, but I cannot use configService nor anything quite like that in there... I could use a env('DB_URL') as the docs tells me to do, but I'd like to keep using the same pattern all over my application, so I'd rather stick with configService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I published this question, I ended up finding the answer I needed much closer than I tought: Basically, I had to set the URL on my PrismaClient (as peer the [NestJS Prisma doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/prisma)) like this:

```js
[...]
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { exampleConfig } from './config/app.config';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient
  implements OnModuleInit {

[...]

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  datasources: {
    db: {
      url: exampleConfig(configService),
    },
  },
})
```

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#programmatically-override-a-datasource-url

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30693040)

Comment: @camille you're totally right! I just edited my answer in order to improve it, thanks for the heads up!